# Using IntersectionObserver to trigger gsap animations when in view

Tags: javascript, gsap

https://codepen.io/OscarTBeamish/pen/1130adf7066be1a390a3cb4d9c46f212

I'm looping through elements with the class 'animate' then adding a timeline to each then using IntersectionObserver to play the animation when in view.

```
    // Intersection observer stuff
    var callback = function (entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(function (entry) {
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                entry.target.timeline.play();
            }
        });
    };
    var observerOptions = {
        rootMargin: '100px',
        threshold: 1.0
    };

    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, observerOptions);

    // Animation logic
    var animations = document.querySelectorAll(".animate");
    animations.forEach(function (el, index) {
        masterTL = new TimelineLite({
            paused: true
        });
        var tl = new TimelineLite();

        if($(el).hasClass('background')) {

            tl.to(el, {
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                x: 0,
                duration: 1
            })
            // return
            masterTL.add(tl);

            el.timeline = masterTL;
        }

        else {
            tl.to(el, {
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                y: 0,
                duration: .6
            })
            .to(el, {
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                opacity: 1,
                delay: -.5,
                duration: .5,
            })

            masterTL.add(tl, index * 0.02);

            el.timeline = masterTL;


        }
        // console.log('still goin');

        observer.observe(el);

    });
```

I've managed to do this successfully on the text but I then want to trigger a different tween for when the element also has a class of 'background'.

Some help would be amazing the idea itself might be wrong to start off with. I just essentially want to trigger different tweens per class when in view.

Comment: It should be noted that GSAP now has an official plugin called [ScrollTrigger](http://greensock.com/scrolltrigger) that can do all that intersection observers can do plus a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Since this answer was posted, GreenSock came out with [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/ScrollTrigger/) which is more useful than intersection observers. Read [the docs](https://greensock.com/ScrollTrigger/) to learn more!

---

**Original answer**

The issue here is that your element never meets the intersection observer's threshold since you have `transform: translateX(-100%)`, even when the parent section is scrolled to.

As such, you should probably either

1. Use a different element as the trigger for that element that *is* in view (my recommendation).
2. Change the -100% to something like -99% and change the threshold value to something (like 0) so it meets the requirements.
3. Use a second intersection observer with different parameters to intersect with just the element that's problematic.

---

Side note: You should use `gsap` instead of `TimelineMax`/`TweenMax` stuff. That's from GSAP 2. See [the GSAP 3 notes](https://greensock.com/3/) for more info. Your code cleaned up a bit (without any of the above suggestions implemented):

```
// Intersection observer stuff
var callback = function (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function (entry) {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      entry.target.timeline.play();
    }
  });
};
var observerOptions = {
  rootMargin: '100px',
  threshold: 1.0
};

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, observerOptions);

// Animation logic
var animations = document.querySelectorAll(".animate");
animations.forEach(function (el, index) {
  el.timeline = gsap.timeline({paused: true});

  if(el.classList.contains('background')) {
    el.timeline.to(el, {
      ease: 'power2.inOut',
      x: 0,
      duration: 1,
    })
  }

  else {
    el.timeline.to(el, {
      ease: 'power2.inOut',
      y: 0,
      duration: .6
    })
    .to(el, {
      ease: 'power2.inOut',
      opacity: 1,
      delay: -.5,
      duration: .5,
    })
  }

  observer.observe(el);

});
```

Comment: thanks for the help man, went with #1 worked perfectly - cheers!